# How do I add origin access control to S3 object within sceptre template?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, access-control, sceptre

I can use AWS console to follow directions and set up an S3 object behind CloudFront using an "origin access control." There's a trickiness in a certain ordering of creating and updating distributions and bucket policies. I've been unable to figure out how to configure all of this in a YAML file for automated deployment using sceptre? I have looked around. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some cloudformation reasources like S3Bucket, BucketPolicy, OriginAccessIdentity and a Cloudfront resources.

[This blog post](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-configure-cloudfront-using-cloudformation-template-2c263u56) will help you